# Preferred method to send tasks alerts / reminders to many users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Each user in our app can create a new task with a specific due date/time (saved in our MySQL database).

We would like to send reminders to users before a task is due.

Is there a best practice (just the general idea) to handle such a thing with Firebase Cloud Messaging? Should there be a CRON job that aggregates all upcoming tasks and then passes them all to FCM? Maybe a different method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful coincidence, I am also working on a project like this and I have to face that problem and searched for many solutions to it.

The solution I am currently working on is:

1- Create a service running in the background, its task is to bring the due date of each task and compare it with the current date, each time period (every five minutes for example)

2- create a child has two values (true or false) within each task in the database and make it false when creating a task, if the task due date exceeds the current time, make that value true.

3- bind (cloud function) with that value and when the value changes from false to true, (cloud function) sends a notification to the specified devices.

maybe this idea helps you, and if you get any other idea for that task share it with me!

Good luck!

Comment: @itai did you get any an idea about this task?